# problem with getting connectionstring from objectcontext.Connection.ConnectionString

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

I really appreciate it if you could ask my question.
After I call myObjectContext.myEntitySet.ToList() method in my entity framework context, the password part from connectionstring in myObjectContext.Connection.ConnectionString is gone.is it a bug?
thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The password is removed to protect you. If you really want to keep the password there you can add the following to your connection string: `Persist Security Info=True;`

So then your connection string should look something like this:

```
Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;
```

Be aware that this is a security risk. If your database server supports windows authentication you should use that instead. Then your connection string would be as follows:

```
Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True
```

As you can see this connection string doesn't contain a user name or password. Instead your windows user name and password is used. If you can you should use this instead of the former.